# How to convert (edited)UIView to UIImage?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview

I want to save changed UIView as UIImage. However, it will always be saved as the first(default) View.

This is the first(default) UIView.

[image]

The app uses Gradient Animation to change the color.
The changed UIView is the same as the following image :

[image]

I wrote the code as following :

```
extension UIImage {
convenience init(layer: CALayer, view: UIView) {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.frame.size)
    layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    self.init(cgImage: (image?.cgImage)!)
    }
}
```

By the way, the image was saved with the default UIView.

How do I save image with the changed UIView?

**[EDIT] Add Animation Code**

```
func animateLayer(){

    if index == 11 {
        addEmitter(a: index, b: 0)
        fromColors = [Colors.fromColorList[index], Colors.fromColorList[0]]
        toColors = [Colors.toColorList[index], Colors.toColorList[0]]
        index = 0
    } else {
        addEmitter(a: index, b: index + 1)
        fromColors = [Colors.fromColorList[index], Colors.fromColorList[index+1]]
        toColors = [Colors.toColorList[index], Colors.toColorList[index+1]]
        index += 1
    }

    animation.fromValue = fromColors
    animation.toValue = toColors
    animation.duration = 1.00

    mind.mindAnimation(animation: animation)

}
```

**[EDIT2] ADD The ViewDidAppear**

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
    animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
    animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear)
    animation.delegate = self
}
```

Comment: Add code for animation too in question. You need to change there.

Comment: @adev add code for animation. Thanks.

Comment: Try this, `animation.removedOnCompletion = false` before adding animation to mind.

Comment: @adev I've done it already (in 'viewDidAppear'). And add the viewdidAppear code

Comment: Is `animateLayer` called before that line in `viewDidAppear`?

Comment: @adev No, animateLayer is called when presses the button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the content of an animated layer during an animation, you should use the presentation layer instead of the view's layer. For your code this should be something like this:

```
if let layer = view.layer.presentation() {
    let image = UIImage(layer: layer, view: view)
    ...
}
```

You should execute this code after the animation has finished an before it is removed from the views layer.

If you don't want to reverse the animation, it should be easier to "revert" it's procedure. That means you swap start and finish colors and set the target colors directly in the view. In this case you needn't keep the animation at animations end, and you can use the view's layer for saving the image.